# try and catch recording data

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have code where if there is a duplicate then it would say "Username already exist". However it proceeds to record the other data like `firstname`, `lastname`, and `middlename` in my database (except for `username`). How can I stop it from recording the other values if there is a duplicate on one data?

```
    Try
      Const SQLStatement As String = "START TRANSACTION; INSERT INTO people(Firstname, Middlename, Lastname) VALUES ( @p0, @p1, @p2); 

INSERT account(uname, pass, type) VALUES( @p3, @p4,@p5); COMMIT;"

                Using connection As New MySqlConnection()
                   connection.ConnectionString = ServerString
                    Dim command As New MySqlCommand(SQLStatement, connection)
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p0", firstname.Value)
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", middlename.Value)
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", lastname.Value)
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", username.Value)
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", password.Value)
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", type.Value)
                    connection.Open()
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End Using
                lblALabel.Text = "Successfully Registered!"
                firstname.Value = ""
                middlename.Value = ""
                lastname.Value = ""
                username.Value = ""
                password.Value = ""
            Catch ex As Exception
                lblALabel.Text = "Username is taken"
            End Try
```

Comment: First check for a record whether the username is already exists or not.If not exists then insert the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...
It will first check the "`UserName`", if it not exists, your data will be inserted.

```
  Try
       Const SQLStatement As String = "IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT WHERE UNAME=@P3) 
       BEGIN 
          START TRANSACTION; 
            INSERT INTO people(Firstname, Middlename, Lastname) VALUES ( @p0, @p1, @p2);
            INSERT account(uname, pass, type) VALUES( @p3, @p4,@p5); 
          COMMIT; 
       END"
      .......
      .......
   Catch ex As Exception
      lblALabel.Text = "Username is taken"
   End Try
```